# Add Class to a div using a filter?

Tags: filters

is it possible to add a dynamic class to a div using a filter in the functions.php? I know it's possible for the body-tag - also for a custom defined div with an id?

```
if ( !is_search() ) {
   $customclass = 'myclass';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using one of the following methods, I don't think there is a specific way to do this other than these two options below.

**Option 1**

In your template file, add the `post_class();` to your div like this:

```
<div id="your-div" <?php post_class(); ?> >
```

Then you can use `post_class` filter in your themes or plugins functions file, something like this:

```
// Add dynamic post class
    function royal_custom_class($classes) {
        global $post;
            $classes[] = 'your-class-name'; // Add your class however its generated here
            return $classes;
    }
    add_filter('post_class', 'royal_custom_class');
```

**Option 2**

Your other option, if the div was defined in your actual content then you could use `the_content` filter and replace and update it.

Something like this:

```
function updated_page_content( $content )
{
     return '<div class="custom_class">Whatever goes inside</div>'. $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'updated_page_content' );
```

**References from Codex for these two methods**

Post Class Filter - [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters)

The Content Filter - [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content#Featured_Image)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like (this goes into functions.php):

```
function add_new_class(){

    if (is_page()) {
    return "page";
} elseif (is_single()) {
    return "post";
} else {
    //add other elseifs
}
}
```

And then, this is how you could call this within different templates:

```
<header class="entry-header <?php echo $new_class = add_new_class(); ?>">
```

WordPress will load different value based on which template (post/page/search/archive, etc.) you are currently on.